# C# call webservice by url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, routes

I'm working on a webapplication and i want to call a webservice through it's url. How can i achieve this?

I've got the following route registered in my global.asax;

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "ServiceHandler",
                "{*path}/{*.svc}",
                new { Url = "Services/Service.svc/GetLatestTweets" }
                );
```

And i want to call the webservice, in this case to get the latest messages from twitter by an url similar to the one below;

```
http://www.domainname.com/Services/Service.svc/GetLatestTweets
```

When i use the registered route as mentioned i'm getting an error with the stackstrace i added below.

```
[ArgumentException: A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route URL.
Parameter name: routeUrl]
   System.Web.Routing.RouteParser.Parse(String routeUrl) +3823656
   System.Web.Routing.Route..ctor(String url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute(RouteCollection routes, String name, String url, Object defaults, Object constraints, String[] namespaces) +86
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute(RouteCollection routes, String name, String url, Object defaults, Object constraints) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute(RouteCollection routes, String name, String url, Object defaults) +18
   CMS.Presentation.FrontEnd.Framework.CMSApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in C:\Projects\Website\Web.Presentation\FrontEnd\Framework\CMSApplication.cs:62
   CMS.Presentation.FrontEnd.Framework.CMSApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Projects\Website\Web.Presentation\FrontEnd\Framework\CMSApplication.cs:80

[HttpException (0x80004005): A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route URL.
Parameter name: routeUrl]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +3988565
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +325
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route URL.
Parameter name: routeUrl]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11529072
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4784373
```

What should i do or change so i can call the webservice by it's url? I'm working with a simple wcf-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but it seems like you could just

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "ServiceHandler",
            "Services/{service}.svc/{*path}",
            new { controller = "services", action = "ParseAndExecuteServiceCall" service = "TwitterService", path = "GetLatestTweets" }
            );
```

and parse the remote call in the controller, if it is more complex.  You can only have one "catchall" parameter in routes, but you can use as many variables as you want, and restrict/define them with IRouteConstraint implementations or Regex patterns.

Also, with response to the comment below about the .svc vs. .mvc handler - There is nothing to limit you from overriding the IHttpHandler  In order to do this, you would need to override the IRouteHandler in's method for GetHttpHandler()...  Then you can do whatever processing you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response :-) Do you have any example how i should handle this in the controller?

Comment: It depends on the services as to how you need to parse the string.  If you were to build a facade for the api, then you could implement a model binder as well, and just have the controller action look like: 

ActionResult ExecuteServiceCall(ServiceFacade service, MethodInfo serviceMethod, NameValueCollection arguments){},

but, it's really all up to you and how you want to do it.  That's probably the best thing.

Comment: Thnx for the response, will try and work it out. One more question occured to me. Why can't i use something like this to just ignore the route?  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  Check out this blog post, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx .  The guy who wrote it is pretty smart.

Comment: I tried several solution with ignoreRoute but i couldn't get it to work unfortunately. In the end i fixed it by registering a route in my appliction on database level (possible due to applcation design) and i was able to call a controller action which would get the information for me from twitter. I left the entire idea of a service

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve this. The `.svc` extension is already registered with a very different handler than MVC in order to process WCF. If you try to change it the service will never work. You might need to call the web service from your controller action which will act as bridge.

Comment: Thnx for the quick response. Too bad this isn't possible as i thought it out, will try it with an controller as bridge